# Replace all 'S with 's unless there's a character after s?

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, vb.net

I want to create ProperCase text function that converts:

```
O'Shanesy, Ben'S and frank'S tires
```

to:

```
O'Shanesy, Ben's and Frank's tires
```

How can I get strReturn.Replace("'S", "'s") to only work when there isn't a character after the s?

```
Public Function fProperCase(ByVal strTextIn As String, Optional ByVal bolIncludingAnd As Boolean = True) As String

        Dim strReturn As String = strTextIn.Trim

        strReturn = StrConv(strTextIn, VbStrConv.ProperCase)

        If bolIncludingAnd = False Then
            strReturn = strReturn.Replace("And", "and")
        End If

        'Change all 'S to 's unless there is 
        'another letter straight after
        strReturn.Replace("'S", "'s")

        Return strReturn

    End Function
```

Comment: This should do it - `strReturn.Replace("'S ", "'s ")`

Comment: AmarDuplantier Excellent though what about if the phrase is O'Shanesy, Ben'S and frank'S. Update: No prob I can just inspect the last two characters. Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately it wouldn't work on punctuation, eg. It would still be "Ben'S" if it was "O'Shanesy, Ben'S, and frank's"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might need to use the Regex indicator end of word.

\b - A word break and will work for both spaces and end of lines.

```
strReturn = Regex.Replace(strReturn, "'S\b", "'s")
```